# Cannot cout char* string in my code

Tags: c++, windows, string, char

I have a statement for displaying a `char*` string. but I do not see anything printed on screen when I try to `cout` a `char*` string. Below is my code:

```
char* reverseString(char *inputString)
{
    int i=0, length=0;
    char *reversedString = (char*)malloc(100);
    strcpy(reversedString,inputString);
    while(inputString[i]!='\0')
    {
        i+=1;
        length+=1;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        reversedString[i]= inputString[length-i];
    }
    cout<<endl<<"In Function, Reversed String: "<<*reversedString<<endl;
    return reversedString; 
}
int main()
{
    char string[100],*reversedString;
    cout<<"Enter string: ";
    scanf("%s",string);
    cout<<"\nString is: "<<string;
    reversedString = reverseString(string);
    cout<<endl<<"In Main, Reversed String: "<<*reversedString<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I see someone just starting out using both `cout` and `malloc`, it really makes me wonder _where_ you are getting these examples?  Why mixing these parts of `C` and `C++`?  `cout` and `scanf()` is even a bigger head-scratcher.

Comment: Did you try it without dereferencing `reversedString`?

Comment: Why use `scanf` instead of `std::cin`?

Comment: Oh, and unless this is for an exercise, you should probably use [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).

Comment: @Chad:  There seem to be some "C++ is just a better C" profs out there insisting on these chimeras...

Comment: @JoeZ Yeah, that's my fear.  `C++`, especially with the new features of `C++11` and upcoming `C++14`, make the language much more natural to use, and the basic language support is getting far removed from "the old `C` way".  Not that there is anything wrong with `C`, but if you want to learn a language, you should learn _that_ language.  It's like giving up all western languages in favor of Latin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start your `for` loop in `reverse` function with `i = 1`. And then add one more statement `reversedString[i] = '\0'` to append your string with `\0`.

Answer (score 5):

It's because you reverse the whole string *including the terminating `'\0'` character*. So in the reversed string the very first character is the string terminator (and the last is the original strings first character, so if you skip "reversing" the terminator then the string is unterminated).